# imprimir etiquetas <script> en un div con jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Me gustaria saber como imprimir etiquetas script en el html con jquery

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el método [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) para agregarlo al final del contenido de un elemento, voy a asumir que en tu caso el div tiene un `id="miDiv"`:

```
$("#miDiv").append("<script>...</script>");
```

Si lo que quieres es reemplazar el texto en el div, puedes usar [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) o [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```
$("#miDiv").html("<script>...</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no conteste a la pregunta me gustaría aportar una solución sin utilizar jQuery para quien le pueda interesar.

Es tan sencillo como crear una etiqueta script con el método [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) y añadirle el atributo src con la ruta a tu fichero .js por medio de [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute). Después, tan solo queda añadirlo al head de tu documento.

```
const scriptTag = document.createElement('script')
scriptTag.setAttribute('src', 'http://example.com/tu.script.js')
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag)
```

Un código algo más extenso que en la versión jQuery pero bastante legible e igualmente eficiente.

Answer (score 0):

Con la función .text de jQuery puedes mandar imprimir codigo html y javascript.

```
   $("#myDiv").text("<script></script>");
```

Saludos...

Comment: Esta no es una buena solución. `text()` limpiará las etiquetas de la cadena y reemplazará las llaves por su código, por lo que no se estará añadiendo una etiqueta `<script>` sino una cadena de texto con `&lt;script&gt;`

Comment: Quizás no entendí bien. había entendido que quiere mostrar las etiquetas de script en su documento html,  que estas no sean renderizadas por el navegador.